# what is github.ref when merging PR to master

Tags: github, github-actions, git-workflow

when I use github.ref in a workflow, that triggers when pushed, I know that it refers to the branch that pushed changes.
When I merge that PR, the same workflow runs, but now I'm not sure if github.ref refers to the **master** or to the branch that originally pushed the changes.

**some more info about what I'm trying to do:**

I want to start using github workflow concurrency while grouping by github.ref to cancel previous workflows.

the only problem is I don't want to cancel test workflows that are triggered as result of pushing to master.

in my workflow I have:

```
concurrency:
  group: ${{github.ref}}
  cancel-in-progress: true
```

if github.ref refers to master when merging a PR then it will delete previous runs for other merges

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: It is the number of the pull request with some more characters added. Thus, you can use it for good concurrency control.

> The fully-formed ref of the branch or tag that triggered the workflow run. For workflows triggered by push, this is the branch or tag ref that was pushed. For workflows triggered by pull_request, this is the pull request merge branch. For workflows triggered by release, this is the release tag created. For other triggers, this is the branch or tag ref that triggered the workflow run. This is only set if a branch or tag is available for the event type. The ref given is fully-formed, meaning that for branches the format is `refs/heads/<branch_name>`, for pull requests it is `refs/pull/<pr_number>/merge`, and for tags it is `refs/tags/<tag_name>`. For example, `refs/heads/feature-branch-1`.

Source: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables

Hints:

- Use [Debug action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debug-action) to output all variables set by GitHub.
- Use [Branch names action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/branch-names) to have "nice" format of branch names